# Discord.js Send message to certain guild in a certain channel

Tags: discord.js

I wan't to make my Shards send a message to my test guild when they send a **death**, **reconnecting**, **disconnected** and **ready** event.

I know I can do it by defining a **specific guild** using its **ID** and a **channel ID** in that guild, but how can this be achieved?

I have no idea and I need your help.

Comment: I am not quite sure whether this is what you are asking, but to find a specific guild: `message.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id === '<id of specific guild here>');`
And to find the channel id in the guild: `client.channels.get('<id of specific channel>')`
If this was not what you were asking please explain further

Comment: Take for example, i have the bot in 2 servers. I want to report the shard events to one of the 2 servers. Specific channel in a specific guild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the job

```js
client.shard.broadcastEval(`this.channels.cache.get("${channelId}")?.send("${message}")`)
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardClientUtil?scrollTo=broadcastEval

Comment: Okay, ill check this out now and ill tell you if it did the job.